# Java - multithreaded copy-on-write

Tags: java, copy-on-write

Is it possible to add software enforced copy-on-write for multithreaded applications in Java? By this I mean threads having a reference to the same object, but when one thread attempts to modify it, the object pointed to is copied and the reference is adjusted to point to that copy.

Comment: Can you please elaborate.. a little bit?

Comment: As this is question currently worded, I have to vote close. Please edit with a much better explanation.

Comment: I mean, depending on what you're asking, effectively that's what you *have* in Java when talking about objects shared across threads without a synchronization mechanism being employed when the contents of said object are modified.

Comment: @BrianRoach Unfortunately, you don't get any guarantees for that...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik define "guarantees" ? The behavior is well defined in the JLS 17.4.

Comment: The edit to the question, however, is clarifying it to not be related.

Comment: @BrianRoach The well-defined behavior you are talking about gives no copy-on-write guarantees---moreover, it gives *no guarantees whatsoever* for variables modified under a data race.

Answer (score 2):

The only implementation I know is the

```
java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList
```

see

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

and the related Set class

```
java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet
```

and finally

```
org.apache.mina.util.CopyOnWriteMap
```

but it depends from your need.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is,

> is it possible to enforce copy-on-write behavior *across the board* for an entire Java runtime

then the answer is,

No, there is no such general capability in Java.

Actually, I think the closest you can possibly get to that goal is using Clojure. All its default data structures are copy-on-write internally, and on the outside they are simply *immutable* objects.

The references you talk about are called, surprisingly, `ref`s and they support full in-memory transactions. A simpler kind of a reference is `atom`, which fits your description 100%.

The whole Core API is devoted to elegant and epressive manipulation of these structures in a thread-safe, lock-free manner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Lazy copying is easy to implement, but you would generally have to do it yourself.